# When deleting data from SQLite database, app requires restart before deletion actually occurs

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Currently I am trying to create a phonebook app that, when the delete button is clicked will delete the entry in the SQLite database that is shown on screen. However, when I click the delete button the method runs but the data stays in the sql database table until I restart the emulator I am using. On restart the data table has updated itself and my "Next" and "Previous" buttons do not pick up the data that was previously deleted.

Does anyone know why this is? I will put some of the relevant code..

```
public void Deletedata (View view)
    {
        int dRow;
        dRow = Integer.parseInt((cursor.getString(0)));
        db.deleteRecord(dRow);      
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Nextdata(view);             


    }

public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
    {


        EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        EditText phoneTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Phone);
        EditText emailTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);

        if (c!= null)
        {
        nameTxt.setText(c.getString(1));
        phoneTxt.setText(c.getString(2));
        emailTxt.setText(c.getString(3));
        }

    }





    public void Nextdata (View view)
    {

        if (cursor.moveToNext())
        { 
            DisplayRecord(cursor);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Last Entry in Phone Book", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Previousdata(view);
        }




    }

    public void Previousdata (View view)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToPrevious())
        { 
            DisplayRecord(cursor);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "First Entry in Phone Book", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Nextdata(view);
        }
```

This piece of code is in my DBAdaptor class,

```
public boolean deleteRecord(long rowId)

    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;


    }



public Cursor getAllRecords() 

    {       
        Cursor gaRecords = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                        KEY_PHONENUMBER, KEY_EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);

        gaRecords.moveToFirst();

                    return gaRecords;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh your Cursor. My best guess for your code is:

```
public void Deletedata (View view)
{
    int position = cursor.getPosition();

    int dRow;
    dRow = Integer.parseInt((cursor.getString(0)));
    db.deleteRecord(dRow);      
    Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Refresh the cursor
    cursor.close();
    cursor = db.getAllRecords();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    Nextdata(view);             
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I just added a couple more lines to show the appropriate record, rather than moving back to the beginning.  But know you understand that the Cursor is just a "snapshot" of the database, it does not have current data.